# Change Table Caption Numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, captions

I want to change the caption number from 2.1 to 2.3.1 as my section is 2-3. I got try to use `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithin{table}{section}` but due to my section title is 2-3. It will label the '2.3.1' that I want as '2-3.1'. Anyone know how to change?

[image: Section title]

[image: Using counterwithin method]

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the table to be numbered `2-3.1` and *not* `2.3.1`, correct?

Comment: i want the table to be numbered as 2.3.1, not 2-3.1. I use the \counterwithin{table}{section} will produce 2-3.1, but i want 2.3.1 :D

Comment: Is `2` the section and `3` the subsection and `1` the table?

Comment: erm, i am not really sure, but the 'Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors' is inside chapter 2. So i guess is chapter 2, section 3 and table 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) is meant to manage counter resetting from continuous to per-unit and *vice versa*. However, you're interested in adjusting the counter representation. To do so add

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}
```

to your document preamble. The default would be to use

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
```

which would inherit the hierarchy associated with the section numbering (also, typically, `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`), and pass it on to the table numbering. For what it's worth, this is a good thing, since the numbering style matches across the hierarchy and is consistent.